# How do I make it so one p5.js drawing appears when I click a radio button?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, radio-button, p5.js

I have created a p5.js drawing wherein when you click a radio button the p5.js drawing changes. When I click the first radio button, it works fine, but then I click the second one and the former drawing is still there. How do I make it so only one drawing appears when I click the second radio button?

Radio button html:

```
<input type="radio" name="radionbutton" value="one" id="button1" onchange="checkM()"/>
<input type="radio" name="radionbutton" value="two" id="button" onchange="checkS()"/>
```

Javascript:

```
var button1 = document.getElementById("button1");
var button2 = document.getElementById("button2");



function drawDonut() {
  console.log("Redrawing our donut!");

  background(218, 24, 132);

  
}

function checkS(){
  document.getElementById("button").checked;
  circle(200,200,200);
}

function checkM(){
  document.getElementById("button1").checked;
  circle(100,100,100);
}

function setup() {
  
  
  myCanvas = createCanvas(400, 400);

  drawDonut();
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: `document.getElementById("button1").checked` is good but should be used in an `if` statement, otherwise it's a no-op.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My attempt is to do the process of displaying and removing the circles inside `p5js draw() function` like so.

```js
var button1 = document.getElementById("button1");
var button2 = document.getElementById("button2");

function draw() {
  background(218, 24, 132);
  if (button1.checked) {
    circle(200,200,200)
  }
  if (button2.checked) {
    circle(100,100,100)
  }
}

function checkS() {
  button1.checked;
}

function checkM() {
  button2.checked;
}

function setup() {
  myCanvas = createCanvas(400, 400);
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

canvas {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.6.0/p5.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.6.0/addons/p5.sound.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>

<body>
  <main>
  </main>
  <input type="radio" name="radionbutton" value="one" id="button1" onchange="checkS()" />
  <label for="button1">S</label><br>
  <input type="radio" name="radionbutton" value="two" id="button2" onchange="checkM()" />
  <label for="button2">M</label><br>
  <script src="sketch.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```